# Rails 3 Paperclip Polymorphic not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, plugins, upload

Anybody know that the polymorphic paperclip working in rails 3 or not??
When i try to create a new object which includes "acts_as_polymorphic_paperclip"
Its saying the same is not found.I installed the plugin and the generator also not working. :(
pls reply

Comment: I would love to know how to solve this problem *heads off to google*